# Documents required for traveling to Istanbul for Syrian nationality with Saudi Arabian residence permit

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, turkey, syrian-citizens

What documents are required to travel to Istanbul from Saudi Arabia with a Syrian nationality.

Comment: Passenger has a residence permit of Saudi Arabia

Answer (score 2):

Per Timatic, the system used by airlines, the following are required:

- Passport / travel documents valid for a minimum of 150 days from the arrival date,  printed in the Latin alphabet and containing at least 1 unused visa page excluding the page reserved for "Observations" or "Amendments and Endorsements".
- A visa

([Source](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b))